# When debugging C# in VS with unity tools for VS, all variables are out of scope

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, scope

Pretty straight forward, when I try to debug an async method in VS2017 using the newest VSTU any variable that *should* be in scope, is out of scope...

Example:
[image]

The only thing that seems in scope is some empty object that I think represents the async task.

Did I miss a checkbox somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you execute the next line?

Comment: @MickyD well, that line specifically will step into the function `SendWithReplyAsync`. There are no local variables in scope there either (there should be)

Comment: ...continuing to debug do you ever encounter a `NullReferenceException`?  The reason I ask is that I too have been using UTVS for years and I find it buggy sadly even before MS bought them out.  I suspect it is a `false alarm`.   Let me know how you go

Comment: @MickyD yes actually, a little later on I get that exception but I can also print out the apparantly null variable in the console sooooo... How do you get around it? Use mono develop?

Comment: You could, but not that extreme.  I started to follow what the makers of the game _Homeworld: Deserts of Kharak_ did - adopted a MVVM pattern and did the bulk of their development in straight up Visual Studio with minimal amount in Unity.  Separation of concerns. See what I wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463149/585968

Comment: @MickyD interesting... Although I would really like to find a solution to my immediate problem, the MVVM pattern is something I could look into later on. Do you have any other ideas I could try? This one bug is really stopping me from completing a *huge* part of the development..

Comment: (no worries) Is it just `async` methods that have this problem?  Also open up VS's **Debug.Windows.Locals** and make sure the objects are showing up there.

Comment: @MickyD See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: It's a bug.  Look [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/debugging-with-async-and-await.495026/)

Quoting Unity3D forums:

[image]

Upgrading to visual studio 2017 Preview 4.0 fixes this issue.

Comment: Great another bug.  That's rather bad considering Unity has had `async/await` for some time now.  Really recommend the MVVM route if you are able to.  Wishing you well

Comment: oh meant to say I summarised that link a bit just in case it breaks by including a snapshot.  feel free to revise

Comment: @MickyD Nope! Looks good to me! Thanks for all your help. I agree it is a bit ridiculous for this bug to exist... I was able to "fix" it by upgrading to the preview 4.0 of VS2017. It seems to work now!

Comment: Great to hear.  Don't forget to check out the YouTube vid.  Even if you don't go MVVM, they have some other gems in there you might like too.  Wishing you well