# How to detect empty IEnumerator function calls during unit testing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enumerator

I'm working with Unity's play mode test unit that run on Enumerator function (aka. Coroutine).

Inside the test, they will call more sub routines, some of them are ordinary function, some of them are IEnumerator function, thus allowing the test to run and span over several frames.

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator Test1( )
{
    SubAction1( );
    yield return SubAction2( );
}

void SubAction1( ) // A sub function that does not need to run over several frames
{ 
}

IEnumerator SubAction2( ) // A sub function that need to span over several frames
{
    ... // More code
    yield return WaitForSeconds( 1 );

    ... // More code
    while( condition == false )
        yield return null; // Wait until condition becomes true to continue

    ... // More code
}
```

If I misuse the `SubAction2` and call it just like ordinary function:

```
SubAction2( ); // without yield return, this is misuse
```

it would still compile and run silently! This will make SubAction2 does not execute all of its code. It is just a small typo, but this one could cause the entire test to fail silently! SubAction2 is an IEnumerator function, and meant to be called with yield return.

Do I have some way to sanity check, or enforce that this function should be called with 'yield return'?

I'm looking for any possible solution of:

- Some C# language pattern to prevent such misuse, either on runtime or compile time.
- OR some magic attribute that will help checking this misuse?
- OR an editor warning that help detecting such misuse (Such as option in VisualStudio intellisense?)

My solution for now is to name all IEnumerator function with some prefix like "DoSubAction2" and then do a regular expression search to find the occurrence of "Do" function calls without "yield return" to manually check for misuse.

Comment: Comment to question reviewer: Although question itself has some relation to GameDev SE, it is focused more on C# langauge side so I would ask it here.

Comment: Btw, there's really no reason to use legacy coroutines in Unity when you have access to `async/await` now.  Whilst the former was popular prior to the introduction of .NET Framework 4.x+, it tended to raise an eyebrow by `C#` developers in general when it was seen how `yield` was being used

Comment: What IDE are you using? Rider and afaik also VisualStudio (but maybe it was just Resharper ^^) warn about that ;)

Comment: @derHugo I'm using visual studio, but without resharper. Hey good to know that it offer such function. I will keep that in mind. But due to economic choice, I will try to find some alternative first.

Comment: @MickyD Thanks for the tip, but for this practical case, I will have to work with coroutines for now. And a bit of side-topic, I believe it is not fully interchangeable. See www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eKi6NKri6I (Async vs. coroutines - By Unity official)

Comment: @Wappenull sure it may not work across all the Unity APIs but then again I was referring to user code and pretty much every co-routine code I've seen on SO is essentially a _logical sleep_.  Thanks for the link though, have bookmarked for later

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is nothing wrong with calling a method that returns an IEnumerator as a method. You now have a generator instead of a coroutine. You're looking to get some kind of warning about "unused returns".

Comment: @NSJacob1 That's quite right, discussion from earlier comment also has helped me pointing into better direction. I'm now trying to see if I can make "Roslyn Analyzer" to warn about such case. (Or write one) If possible, I will come back to write as an answer, well, if question is not hammered first :/ I'm always on such pace on SO, asking too much specific question and then boom...

Comment: As a Unity specific option, you could also write an asset postprocessor and parse/use reflection to figure out if some policy is being broken. Having never written a Roslyn Analyzer I can't say which is easier, although I'd prefer just getting a warning in the IDE.

Comment: Your coroutines could use an interface parameter to be called on completion. Then you can check that interface invoke for Execute. That is syntax for NSubstitute.

Comment: Another option of course is to have [as much code outside of Unity as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463149/585968).  Not only does it speed development but it frees you from being placed in a corner during development and testing.  **Blackbird Interactive** the makers of the arguably AAA-quality _Homeworld: Deserts of Kharak_ [did exactly that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9aeNtKKXeo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking with available options, I decided to go with Visual Studio VSIX extension and write a **Roslyn analyzer**. Such misuse will be prompted in IDE as warning.

[image]

For the sake of completion, I have uploaded all analyzer/fixer code there: [Github](https://github.com/wappenull/EnumeratorCallAnalyzer/blob/master/EnumeratorCallAnalyzer/EnumeratorCallAnalyzer/EnumeratorCallAnalyzerAnalyzer.cs)

These are guides I used:

- [Roslyn Analyzers and how to use them with Unity](https://arztsamuel.github.io/en/blogs/2019/Roslyn-Analyzers-and-Unity.html) (This article also show other practical examples on how to use analyzer to enforce coding style)
- [Writing a Roslyn analyzer (meziantou.net)](https://www.meziantou.net/writing-a-roslyn-analyzer.htm)
- [How to write a Roslyn Analyzer (devblogs.microsoft)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/)

### Other relevant stuff

- According to @derHugo. Looks like **Resharper** (requires paid subscription) will also warn about this pattern.
- There is also an open source project [Roslynator2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=josefpihrt.Roslynator2019) which bundle tons of code analyzers which focus on code design in general C# and it is free. But sadly it does not include my case.
- Looks like C# async-await could also be used with Unity unit test. It just need some enclosure like what [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) provided.

*I would like to thank everyone in the discussion. And for readers, I hope you learned something new today.*

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  You might want to check out the static code analysis and reporting tool _[nDepend](https://www.ndepend.com/)_.    You can customise it with your own rules via LINQ-ish language to check code at author-time as well as during nightly builds.  [See also...](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2019/08/10/under-the-hood-a-systems-unit-tests-are-no-indication-of-the-quality-of-the-source-code/)

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as you are basically trying to guide yourself while writing tests, you could go for a scenario where you always call a certain 'helper' method and let the compiler instruct you if you are wrong.

An option is using a baseclass or utility dictating the way of calling methods.
You can then create a method with overloads, handling IEnumerators or regular methods.

```
private void Test1()
{
    CallMethod(MethodNoParams);

    CallMethod(() => MethodOneParam(1));

    CallMethod(CoroutineMethod());

    CallMethod(MethodNoParams()); // Does not compile
    CallMethod(CoroutineMethod); // Does not compile
    CallMethod(MethodOneParam(1)); // Does not compile
}

private void MethodNoParams()
{

}

private void MethodOneParam(int something)
{

}

private System.Collections.IEnumerator CoroutineMethod()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}



// These methods in utility or base class
public void CallMethod(Action method)
{
    method.Invoke();
}


public void CallMethod(System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator)
{
    StartCoroutine(enumerator);
}
```

Comment: I were also think of something similar to this, this pattern is doable but it will lose the wait-for-completion functionality, such as `CoroutineMethod` (line7) to finish before continuing to `MethodNoParams` :)